# Is there a way to use Apple Pay as an NFC tag with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid, applepay

Is there a way to use my iPhone as an ID card with Apple Pay? I know this is achievable for some Student ID cards. However I want to integrate it with my Arduino (I'm using the RC522 reader.)

I have a code snippet that I downloaded that works with static NFC tags. However, I have figured out that Apple Pay generates a unique Identifier with each scan.

Ideally, I would be able to touch my iPhone to the RFID reader, confirm "apple pay", and have the system detect that it is a valid device.

Again, I have the first two parts working, but it currently will accept any device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have a few hurdles. You would use an NFC enabled Apple Wallet pass.

Your NFC reader would need to support the  VAS protocol and enhanced contactless polling, you would then need to have a NFC signing certificate from Apple and you would need to implement Apple’s decryption utility to get a consistent payload from each scan.

There’s more info here: [PassNinja](https://passninja.com)

Full Disclosure: I work for PassNinja.